# Error that send files into Minio Object Storage

Tags: apache-nifi, minio, object-storage

I am trying to send files into Minio Object storage Using Apache NiFi.

Here are the scenario example:

1. Create files using NiFi GenerateFlowFile processor
2. Send the created files into Minio Object Storage using NiFi PutS3Object processor

Note: In Minio Object Storage I created a bucket name called "test"

It came out with this error:

> Error checking S3 Multipart Upload list for /test: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListMultipartUploadsHandler

Here is the NiFi setup:

[Scenario NiFi setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq2g5.png)

GenerateFlowFile Processor:

[Generated Flow File Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Qbe.png)

PutS3Object processor:

[PutS3Object processor 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU0PN.png)

[PutS3Object processor 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bASrV.png)

[PutS3Object processor 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7ixQ.png)

My Minio Interface where bucket is created :

[Minio Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/medC9.png)

Could someone please help me with this error with explanation and example ? Thanks & appreciate.